# C# WinForm: Select specific words and change colour

Tags: winforms, colors

I have a program that allows the user to enter text, and it will highlight any repeat words. It already adds repeated words to one list and all the words to another. I want the program to print out the words, and if a repeat word is used, to highlight it.

I have tried using `outputBox.Find(repeatList[i])` with a loop, but this only finds the first word used in the text. I also tried marking the current number for the last letter typed, selecting that point, finding the coordinates after the word.Length was typed, and then changing the colour of that, which didn't work.

```
        for (int h = 0; h < repeatList.Count; h++)
        {
            for (int c = 0; c < repeatList.Count; c++)
            {
                outputBox.Find(repeatList[h]);
                outputBox.SelectionColor = Color.Red;
            }
        }
```

At this point in the code, the outputBox already contains the users input, I just want to know how to compare words and select them for colouring. I've only just started Winforms and have only been coding for a few weeks, so I am sorry - I have looked at other answers but was not able to implement them. Thank you in advance for any responses.

EDIT: I would just like to add that my prefered method for colouring the text would be as it prints each word out, this was my original intention as I'm much more used to console applications where I can just change the colour and print more. If that method is easier to do than checking afterwards, I'm find to do that.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the start index and keep a copy of it.

```
int startFrom = 0
...
startFrom = outputBox.Find(repeatList[h], startFrom)
```

You could then use the 'startFrom' index with the text word length to select the text.

Here is an example:

```
    var findText = "test";
    int index = 0;
    do
    {
        index = richTextBox1.Find(findText, index, RichTextBoxFinds.WholeWord);
        if (index > -1)
        {
            richTextBox1.Select(index, findText.Length);
            richTextBox1.SelectionColor = Color.Red;
            index++;
        }
    } while (index > -1);
```